# How can I use "react-owl-carousel-rtl"?

Tags: reactjs, owl-carousel

I want to install react-owl-carousel-rtl
I followed the instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel-rtl

But still it does not work for me because of the direction: rtl

This is the code I wrote-

```
import OwlCarousel from "react-owl-carousel";
import "owl.carousel / dist / assets / owl.carousel.css";
import "owl.carousel / dist / assets / owl.theme.default.css";

<OwlCarousel loop={false} rtlClass="owl-rtl" margin={10}>
  <div>
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
</OwlCarousel>
```

Regards

Comment: its not clear from your question what isn't working. Can you explain what you expect and what's actually happening instead?

Comment: @AndrewLohr I will explain myself, when I make a number of objects, the first on the far left. Which shows that the problem is because of the rtl. But it bothers me less, it just shows that it's the root of the problem.The main problem is that they do not get slides. When there are a large number of objects or loops it shows nothing. Because it moves left and not right "and exits the page"

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem and unfortunately, the documentation was wrong!

so you need to change the `import` and add `rtl` property like this:

```
import OwlCarousel from "react-owl-carousel-rtl";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css";

<OwlCarousel loop={false} rtlClass="owl-rtl" margin={10} rtl={true}>
  <div>
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
</OwlCarousel>
```

that worked for me :)